# Listview not updating after arraylist is updated?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I've seen many other posts in this context, but none helped. Problem is when i click on the addField button, the listview inside dialog adds new view just once. But at other clicks it doesn't get updated though The adapter works correctly (I mean the getView is called and also the arrayList in the adapter is changed in size).

I've used notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter class. No result! I used an instance of adpater class in activity and called myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). No result!

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvfid;
FieldAdapter fAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //some code
    showFid();
}

private void showFiD(){
    final ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this , R.style.DialogTheme);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.field_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    Button addField = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfidField);
    lvfid = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvfid);
    //Another plan i have tested, but no result:
    //fAdapter = new FieldAdapter(dialog.getContext(),al);
    //lvfid.setAdapter(fAdapter);
    addField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            HashMap<String,String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();
            h.put("name", "");
            h.put("value", "");
            al.add(h);
            lvfid.setAdapter(new FieldAdapter(dialog.getContext(), al));
            //fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}

public class FieldAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private ArrayList <HashMap <String,String>> arrayList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public FieldAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap <String,String>> arrayList) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_inflater, null);
     else 
        view = convertView;
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    holder.edName     = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edfidName);
    holder.edValue     = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edfidValue);
    //holder.edName.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("name"));
    //holder.edValue.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("value"));
    return view;
}

private class Holder {
    private EditText edName;
    private EditText edValue;
}


}

}
```

***UPDATE:
I'm sorry i took everybody's time. The stupid problem was that my listview was inside a scrollview where it must not be! I hope this helps others who have the same issue!***

Comment: Use the notifyDataSetChanged() every time the list is updated.

Comment: lvfid.setAdapter should be done only once I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry i took everybody's time! The stupid problem was just my listview was inside a scrollview where it must not be! after getting the listview out of scrollview the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the notifyDataSetChanged() every time the list is updated.

Comment: Actually i had done that, but no result! I updated the question to add the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was facing with this problem when I wanted to update the listView after `onDateChanged()`. I resolved it with an extra ArrayList variable and an extra custom adapter in your case `FieldAdapter` variable.

Update your listView with a refresh adapter and array list variables after any operations. For example after button clicks.

**1.** Define a counter.
**2.** Check when the button is clicked, increase counter by one
**3.** Every time check the counter, if counter is greater than 1 it means the button is clicked more than once so update the list view with new variables `(arrayList, FeildAdapter)`

I recommend you to define the variables as a private class fields and name them such as `refreshedArrayList` and `refreshedAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

1. Option

Try to use the ArrayAdapter. And don't create a new adapter every
time you click on the button.

only call the add(T o) function from the ArrayAdapter.

2. Other Option:

add a add function to your FieldAdapter in the add field adapter add the object to your arraylist and call notifiyDataSetChanged(the adapter has aslo one and the adapter notifies all his observers)

also don't create a new adapter every time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvfid;
FieldAdapter fAdapter;
ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>> al ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //some code

    al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    lvfid.setAdapter(new FieldAdapter(MainActivity.this , al));

    showFid();
    }

    private void showFiD(){
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this , R.style.DialogTheme);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.field_dialog);
         dialog.setCancelable(true);
         dialog.show();
         Button addField = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfidField);
         lvfid = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvfid);
         //Another plan i have tested, but no result:
         //fAdapter = new FieldAdapter(dialog.getContext(),al);
         //lvfid.setAdapter(fAdapter);
         addField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             HashMap<String,String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();
             h.put("name", "");
             h.put("value", "");
             al.add(h);
             fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is this tested? lvfid.setAdapter can't be called at onCreate because it lvfid is in a dialog context!